# SQL SELECT query that GROUP when 2 values are combined either way

Tags: date, select, group-by, where-clause

these problem starts to give me headache so I try to find some help here as I can't find a similar problem... I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I have the following table:

```
id / id_sender / id_receiver / date
1  /    1      /      2      / 07/08/2013
2  /    3      /      1      / 08/08/2013
3  /    3      /      1      / 09/08/2013
4  /    1      /      3      / 10/08/2013
5  /    2      /      3      / 11/08/2013
6  /    2      /      1      / 12/08/2013
```

I try to do an SQL query that:

```
SELECT rows WHERE id_sender or id_receiver = 1
```

So here I would get rid of the ID 5

```
GROUP them when value are identical either way in id_sender and id_receiver
```

Here, 1/6 and 2/3/4 would be grouped

```
SELECT the most recent one in each group
```

This one would pick 6 and 4 respectively in each, which is the result i'd like to get

What have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id_sender = '1' OR id_receiver = '1' 
ORDER BY date
```

But I'm not used with advanced query and I struggle with the grouping as I can't group by ID_sender neither ID_receiver because in both way I would'n get the expected grouping and as I don't have the proper grouping I can't apply a max(date)...

Thanks a lot in advance for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT max_id, min_id, max(date) FROM
(
    SELECT id, 
    case when id_sender>id_receiver then id_sender else id_receiver end max_id,
    case when id_sender>id_receiver then id_receiver else id_sender end min_id,
    date FROM table_name
) g GROUP BY max_id, min_id
```

The idea is to have always the largest one in the max_id and the smallest one in the min_id, so that you can group them.